# Prove an inequality.

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

Prove that $$\displaystyle{(|x_1+y_1|^p + |x_2+y_2|^p +\dots +|x_n+y_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq (|x_1|^p + |x_2|^p +\dots +|x_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}+(|y_1|^p + |y_2|^p +\dots +|y_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}}$$ for all $p\in\Bbb{N}$.

I tried methods like taking the $p$th power on both sides and differentiating with respect to $x_1$, taking the rest of the variables as constants. I didn't get much farther.

**A helpful hint would be great, and would suffice. I am not looking for a solution.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/447747).

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [Minkowski's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality). The easiest proof is using duality as is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/447754). The only tool needed there is [Hölder's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
The expression in question is the $p$-Norm of vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and translates to
$$\lVert x+y \rVert_p \leq \lVert x\rVert_p + \lVert y \rVert_p$$
Prove using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality after taking the $p$-th power elementwise.

Comment: It's funny, that is the exact thing I was trying to prove, which led me to this inequality. So I doubt that would be very helpful in my particular circumstance. Thanks!

Comment: I edited. The standard way utilizes the CS-inequality.

Comment: @AlexR I'm pretty sure you can only use the CS inequality here if $p=2$, the case in which the norm is "induced" by an inner product.

Comment: @jkn For other $p$, use [Minkowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality). The proof is ibid. BTW. So if anyone wants to C&P the answer from wikipedia, go ahead.

Comment: @AlexR, that is the inequality the OP is trying to prove.

Comment: @jkn And the proof can be found on the linked wikipedia page (for general $L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and then restricting to $L^p(\{1,\ldots,n\}, \mathcal{P}(\{1,\ldots,n\}), \#)$ concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $p\geq 1$, then the function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty),x\to x^p$ is convex. That is, for any $x,y\in[0,\infty)$ and $0\leq\theta\leq1$,

$$f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)\leq \theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y).$$