# Comparing the quantity of two Lebesgue integrals of infinite sums

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This is question 2 from [here](https://www.cmu.edu/math/grad/phd/pdfs/measure_and_integration_2020-1.pdf):

> Let $f_n \in L_1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Which is larger,
> $$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\int f_n d\mu\right|^2\right)^{1/2}\label{1}$$
> or
> $$\int \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n|^2\right)^{1/2} d\mu$$

I’ve not made much progress on this question, and I’d like to ask for some help.

Taking the first expression, we have
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\int f_n d\mu\right|^2\right)^{1/2}
& \leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\int |f_n| d\mu\right)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
& \stackrel{\text{Holder}}{\leq}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\int 1 d\mu\right)\left(\int |f_n|^2 d\mu\right)\right)^{1/2}\\
& = \left(\left(\int 1 d\mu\right) \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int |f_n|^2 d\mu\right)\right)^{1/2}\\
& \stackrel{\text{LMCT}}{=} \left(\left(\int 1 d\mu\right) \left(\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n|^2 d\mu\right)\right)^{1/2}\\
& = \left(\int 1 d\mu\right)^{1/2} \left(\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n|^2 d\mu\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
I don’t think what I have is correct. Since there is now an extra $\int 1$ term, and I have no good way of bringing the $\frac{1}{2}$ into the integral. I think at some point I need to make use of the Minkowski inequality.

There is a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520568/which-one-of-the-integral-expression-is-always-larger) making use of the $\ell_p$ spaces, is there any way to avoid it and show this inequality within the $L_p$ spaces?

Comment: Minkowskis (integral) inequality may be helpful

Comment: @Andrew thank you! I’ve not came across the integral form of Minkowski, but this follows immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, an elementary proof is available. For each $N$, consider the vector

$$ \mathbf{f}_N = (f_1, \ldots, f_N) \in (L_1)^N, $$

and let $\| (x_1, \ldots, x_N) \|_{\mathbb{R}^N} = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_N^2} $ denote the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^N$. Then

$$ \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left|\int f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu\right|^2\right)^{1/2}
=  \left\| \int \mathbf{f}_N \, \mathrm{d}\mu \right\|_{\mathbb{R}^N},$$

whereas

$$ \int \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} |f_n|^2\right)^{1/2} \, \mathrm{d}\mu
= \int \|\mathbf{f}_N\|_{\mathbb{R}^N} \, \mathrm{d}\mu. $$

Then a standard argument shows that

$$ \left\| \int \mathbf{f}_N \, \mathrm{d}\mu \right\|_{\mathbb{R}^N}
\leq \int \|\mathbf{f}_N\|_{\mathbb{R}^N} \, \mathrm{d}\mu. $$

> *Proof.* Choose a unit vector $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ pointing to the same direction of $\int \mathbf{f}_N \, \mathrm{d}\mu$:
>
> $$ \int \mathbf{f}_N \, \mathrm{d}\mu
> = \left\| \int \mathbf{f}_N \, \mathrm{d}\mu \right\|_{\mathbb{R}^N} \mathbf{u} $$
> Then
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left\| \int \mathbf{f}_N \, \mathrm{d}\mu \right\|_{\mathbb{R}^N}
> &= \left( \int \mathbf{f}_N \, \mathrm{d}\mu \right) \cdot \mathbf{u}
> = \int (\mathbf{f}_N \cdot \mathbf{u}) \, \mathrm{d}\mu
> \leq \int \|\mathbf{f}_N\|_{\mathbb{R}^N} \, \mathrm{d}\mu.
> \end{align*}

Now letting $N \to \infty$ proves the desired inequality.

---

*Remark.* This approach is not far from the one using Minkowski integral inequality, because the latter can be thought of as a special case of the inequality

$$ \left\| \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) \right\| \leq \int_{\mathcal{X}} \|f(x)\| \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x), $$

where $f : \mathcal{X} \to E$ is an integrable function taking values in a Banach space $E$ and $\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ is the corresponding [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral). Then the Minkowski inequality corresponds to the case where $E$ is an $L^p$-space on another measure space.

Answer (score 0):

By the [general Minkowski inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2355672/121671)

$$\Big(\int_{\mathbb{N}}\Big|\int_Xf_n(x)\,\mu(dx)\Big|^2\,\#(dn)\Big)^{1/2}\leq\int_X\Big(\int_{\mathbb{N}}|f_n(x)|^2\,\#(dn)\Big)^{1/2}\,\mu(dx)$$

where $\#$ is the counting measure on $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}})$ which acts on sequences as
$$\int_{\mathbb{N}}g(n)\,\#(dn)=\sum_n g(n)$$

The assumption that each $f_n\in L_1(\mu)$ implies that $n\mapsto\int_X |f_n(x)|\,\mu(dx)$ is finite.

---

A more pedestrian way to obtain inequality above is by using the finite dimensional version of the problem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3696228/121671)) which yields, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
\begin{align}
\Big(\sum^n_{k=1}\Big|\int_Xf_n\,d\mu\Big|^2\Big)^{1/2}
\leq \int_X\Big(\sum^n_{k=1}|f_n|^2\Big)^{1/2}\,d\mu\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
Then pass to the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and applying monotone convergence on the right-hand-side of \eqref{one}